# snapshots to be stored in the subdirectories depending on the branch name

Tags: maven, repository, teamcity, snapshot, jfrog-cli

**Setup**
 - Let's say i have two java projects - 1.Project-A and 2.Project-B . Both are the interdependent projects.
 - Both the projects have 2 branches each. 1.staging and 2.development
 - Teamcity CI build tool is used to build(mvn clean) the projects.

**Issue**
 - Suppose Build for Project-A is fired referring to master branch.
 - So the snapshot for project-A corresponds to master branch.
 - Again we have fired a build for the same Project-A but referring to staging branch.Now the latest snapshot for project-A corresponds to staging branch.
 - Now i have to fire a build for Project-B of master branch. While fetching the dependencies i want snapshot of Project-A referring to master branch to be fetched but in my case snapshot which corresponds to staging branch is getting fetched.

I want snapshots to be stored under the subdirectories of the respective branch. I tried using plugin from here https://bitbucket.org/mattshelton/maven-branch-extension but it didn't work.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply name the version like `1.0-BRA-SNAPSHOT` and `1.0-BRB-SNAPSHOT` and use a repository manager and the problem is solved (using the following: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) ..

Comment: Just be careful at branching and merging, when changing the names back and forth.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise il try out the above things and will let you know.

Comment: If you configure that in Jenkins (multi branch pipeline) instead of in the pom file it will be easy to merge cause there can't be an issue..

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks..your first comment seems to be working.. but i have issues while getting branch name in teamcity. I tried using %teamcity.build.branch% but it gives me branch name like this - refs/heads/master i want only master

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help in Teamcity cause I don't use Teamcity...

Comment: hmmm.. neways thanks buddy.. Your solution was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In TeamCity, you can do the following:

1. Configure 2 build configurations for Project-A and Project-B
2. In both the VCS root used in those build configurations configure **Branch specification**
3. Configure snapshot and artifact dependency from Project-B to Project-A

I that case Project-B has to be able to build against the artifact dependency located in a file system instead of fetching it via Maven dependency management.

Update: described it in a little more details in a [blog post](https://medium.com/@antonarhipov/building-dependant-maven-projects-d2b71963827a).

Comment: Thanks @Anton Arhipov il try this out.